# angular-material md-card dynamic height

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to make it so my grid of md-cards have different heights depending on their image. Right now if one image is taller the entire row of cards match that height, making for a wonky look. What can I do to make the card content inside the `<md-card>` not stretch to match the row?

[image]

Here is the html for the cards:

```
   <section class="cards" ng-if="view === 'Articles'">
        <div layout="row" layout-align="center stretch" layout-wrap>
          <md-card ng-repeat="article in home.articles | filter:searchCard | orderBy:'-negPos'">
            <a ng-href="/article/{{article.id}}"><img ng-src="{{article.imagePath}}" class="card-image" alt="Article image"></a>
            <div class="card_content">
                <div class="article_card_title">
                    <a ng-href="/article/{{article.id}}"><h3 class="md-subhead">{{article.title}}</h3></a>
                </div>
                <div class="card_agency">
                    <span class="agency_name">{{article.agency}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card_ratings">
                <div>
                <img src="{{article.negPosBar}}">
                    <md-tooltip md-direction="'bottom'">
               </div>
               <div>
                <img src="{{article.skewBar}}">         
               </div>
              <div>
                <img src="{{article.contBar}}">
               </div>
            </div>
          </md-card>
          <h1 class="md-display-1" ng-show="(home.articles | filter:searchCard).length == 0">No results!</h1>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And the css:

```
md-card {
    width: 375px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.card_content {
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: probably set a fixed height for the images?

Answer (score 2):

I have dealing with that too! So, what i did about it was create the following structure:

```
<div layout="row" ng-repeat="itemGroup in itemCollection" layout-wrap>
    <div layout="column"  ng-repeat="item in itemGroup" flex>
        <md-card>
             <!-- card content here... -->
        </md-card>  
    </ng-include> 
</div>
```

As you can see...i'm creating a row (**layout-wrap**) for each group of cards and then i'm just drawing a column (**flex**) for every card. The result, as i expected, has been an auto height behavior for each card!

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a row layout. You append each `md-card` to the same row. This means the row is gonna grow in height according to its tallest child, and other children stretch to match this height. You could have a `div` filling this height, and then the `md-card` to fill the div only partially. But this would mean there is still empty space between the cards on the first and the second row.

The other approach is to make a column layout. According to your picture you would have three columns. Now each `md-card` is appended to one of the columns, below its sibling. Take a look at this two column layout:

```
<div layout="row">
  <div layout="column" flex="50" class="left">
    <md-card ng-repeat="article in home.articles" ng-if="$even">
    </md-card>
  </div>
  <div layout="column" flex="50" class="right">
    <md-card ng-repeat="article in home.articles" ng-if="$odd">
    </md-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here we use the `$even` and `$odd` from `ng-repeat` to split each card to left and right. Making the order look like this:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Of course you would have to figure out how many columns you need with different screen widths.