# How to put the cards dynamically and fill the empty spaces?

Tags: angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

My objective is to do something like this, (the example "Card Action Buttons") https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/card but dynamically.

```
<div class="md-padding" layout="row" layout-xs="column" layout-wrap>
<div flex-gt-xs="50" flex-sm="100" class="blue" ng-repeat="match in matches.matchesList">

    <md-card md-whiteframe="8">
        <md-card-header>
            <md-card-avatar>
                <md-icon class="md-avatar-icon" ></md-icon>
            </md-card-avatar>
            <md-card-header-text>
                <span class="md-title">Title</span>
                <span class="md-subhead">subhead</span>
            </md-card-header-text>
        </md-card-header>

        <md-card-content>
            <!-- Directive to show the score board -->

            <p>
            The titles of Washed Out's breakthrough song and the first single from Paracosm share the
            two most important words in Ernest Greene's musical language: feel it. It's a simple request, as well...
            </p>

        </md-card-content>
    </md-card>

</div>
</div>
```

When the cards have different heights happens this [image: example]

Here is the code but I dont know how to put to work if someone know please tell me to http://codepen.io/TiagoSousa/pen/aNjWqd

The code of the codepen is different and is build to work on everyone because the code I inserted on stack have directives and other stuff you cannot do

Comment: I answered similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587784/angular-material-md-card-dynamic-height/36613500#36613500

Comment: @AnttiVäyrynen I have already seen that but what you have is by column that was the only solution that I found but I dont want to do in column, I wanted to know if it was any other way without changing the data because for me the order they appear is important.

Comment: The problems is that you cannot have two different height children within in on row container. This container always grows according to the height of the tallest child eventually pushing everything downwards on the second row. This is what happens in your picture.

Comment: @AnttiVäyrynen Yeah that is the problem but can you say how i push down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the cards on each row start at the same height because of CSS flexbox (namely `flex-direction: row`), not sure though. One solution would be to split the items you want to show into a left and a right column. Have a look at http://codepen.io/z00bs/pen/XdBgJK (I cleaned up your pen...).

Comment: But for what i saw you are putting by column and the order by that is:
[1 4]
[2 5]
[3 6]

and i want: 
[1 2] 
[3 4]
[5 6] but the visual layout is that.

Comment: @TiagoSousa This is just a matter of how you split up the matches to the two arrays. Check the pen, I've updated it.

Comment: But when i resize the window to a XS it gonna put the [1 3 5 2 6] understand? To see this resize the codepen to a XS and put numbers before the text to see better. But thanks really helped but if you have a ideia to fix this it really would help.

Comment: @TiagoSousa I guess this is not possible (google for flexbox and masonry). You can mimic the behaviour by using `layout="column"` and setting a height on the layout wrapper (see http://codepen.io/z00bs/pen/YqjrXW). Problem is that if there is too much content it flows in a third column.

Comment: I gonna see, thanks a lot for the help i wiil tell you something later.